# Passing parameters between auxiliary outlets

Tags: angular, angular-router

I currently have an auxiliary outlet which only outputs data inside a specific area of my application. This is due to the fact that I want to manipulate the data without changing the dashboard state. My problem is, how do I pass parameters between components inside my auxiliary outlet? This is what I have.

**manage-clients.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let police of agentPaPolicies">
<button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {agentSidebar: ['details', police._id]}}]">View</button>
</div>
```

From the `html` above, I'd like to navigate to path `/details` with param `police._id`. The code  below is my `app.routing.ts` file.

**app-routing.ts**

```
{ path: 'manage-clients', component:ManageClientsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {permission: {only:["agent"]}}, outlet: 'agentSidebar'},
 { path: 'details/:_id', component:DetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {permission: {only:["agent"]}}, outlet: 'agentSidebar'},
```

However, the code above displays an error in my web console like so:

```
URL Segment: 'manage-clients'
Error: Cannot match any routes.
```

How would I change my code to properly route this in order to pass the parameter between both components inside an auxiliary outlet?

Comment: Is this correct? ['details, police._id']
Should it not be ['details’, police._id]

Comment: @JensAlenius hey there, good catch but it was just a typo. I'll edit my question for clarification!

Comment: If you change from a button tag to an anchor tag you will see what url it will navigate to, in the left bottom of the browser, when you hover into the link. That often helps me. When you see what route it will goto. An anchor is better to use when it comes to navigation and routing

Comment: @JensAlenius The issue is that if I route the path from from the auxiliary outlet to the primary outlet instead, the route works but it will display it within the primary outlet which I do not want. Any thoughts? I think the solution may be that I need to set child routes within my auxiliary route to have a proper routing.

Comment: If you want the details route to react to the url: ‘manage-clients/details/1234 it should be below int the children array of manage-clients. But I’m not used to use the outlet property in the route definitions. Sorry. My last comment was just a suggestion to be able to se what routes the routeLink creates

Comment: It's alright. I'll try to set child routes within the auxiliary outlet and see where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really get your setup but if the manage-client is the parent route. Then you can add

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In it’s html and remove any outlet from the route conf.  Skip the outlet name if it’s only one

Any child route will be injected at that place

The routeLink will be relative to beneath ‘manage-client’ so if you write it like

```
  <a [routeLink]=“[‘details’,Id]>Style it like a button<\a>
```

It should point at manage-client/details/1234